# how to show a table when cheked the user info?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to write a code that if you pressed the button and the username and password was correct. then it shows you a table that contains photos and a link to their Instagram.

when ***table*** tag is used inside of a ***function*** in *script* tag the function **breaks** and there is no function in html itself. so where should I put my table to be shown when the button has been pushed?

here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>balalar</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function check(){

var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "user1" && password == "1234"){

        alert("hello user")

    <!--want to put the table here. but it breaks the function-->

    }


      else
      { 
        alert("chek username and password"); 
      }

  } 

</script>

</head>


<body>

<form align="center">

     username:<input type="text" name="username"     id="username" /><br>
     </br>
     password:<input type="password" name="password"     id="password"/><br>
     </br>
     <input type="button" value="login" id="login" onclick="return
     check()"/>

</form>

</body> 

</html>
```

here is my table :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel=stylesheets; href="css.css">
<head>
<title>BALALAR</title>

<style>

table, th, td {

    border:5px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {

    padding: 30px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: pink;
}

th {
    background: gray;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<table align="center">
    <caption style="color: #ff99ac"> <h1>[BALALAR]</h1> </caption>


    <tr> <!--heading------------------------------------------------------------>

        <th>photo</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>info</th>
        <th>instagram</th>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--lucifer------------------------------------------------------------>

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/17d60601e17a27d3a0196470f00c55a4/5CF8DA8C/t51.2885-15/e35/50850072_2165205533518446_3117212119304625148_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>lucifersexdoll</center> </td>
        <td> <center>18</center> </td>
        <td> <center>instagram star and tiktoker</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lucifersexdoll/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--belle delphine----------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6331b02f48e920975e98434c595fd4ee/5CE47C32/t51.2885-15/e35/41760483_210825032975228_2673466538809180596_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="170px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>belle delphine</center> </td> 
        <td> <center>19</center></td>
        <td> <center>instagram star and snapchat thot</center></td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/belle.delphine/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--Georgia Twinn------------------------------------------------------>

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b4cdaabe45fd41c4d36e18c074a0cb71/5CEFBA3C/t51.2885-15/e35/43986219_288982548424250_1512646608107907870_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com" style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" height="200px" width="200" > </center> </td>
        <td> <center>Georgia Twinn</center> </td>
        <td> <center>15</center> </td>
        <td> <center> instagram star and youtuber</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/georgialeetwinn/"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px" > </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--lilsaggester------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7b351d27e76a70aed0dc97ca2946b31/5CF7E289/t51.2885-15/e35/44478694_259861178046212_7053862547100372241_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px" > </center> </td>
        <td> <center>hannah fabel</center> </td>
        <td> <center>16</center> </td>
        <td> <center>tiktoker</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aestheticallyhannah/"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px" > </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--cyxll-------------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fe0da5e3353e102fd30a771e7f18d793/5CEA7C9B/t51.2885-15/e35/50510784_321000775215940_7823002975742791621_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="250px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>cyxll</center> </td>
        <td> <center>unknown</center> </td>
        <td> <center>instagram user</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cyxll/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--gal gadot---------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/85ba393e3d05f6047fea8ac9ee61edd4/5D250597/t51.2885-15/e35/40265259_229384887926581_2920908417464813508_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>gal gadot</center> </td>
        <td> <center>33</center> </td>
        <td> <center>actress</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gal_gadot/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a></center> </td>

    </tr>   


</table>

</body>

</html>
```

want to put different tables for different users later.

Answer (score 1):

You could leave your table in HTML body... and make `#tableID {display: none;}`

In JS:

```
function check(){
  var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
  if(username == "user1" && password == "1234"){
    alert("hello user")
    document.getElementById('tableID').style.display = 'block';
   }
  else {alert("chek username and password");}
}
```

But even if there is too specific code, when you have to place your HTML in JS, you must escape all special characters (search > JavaScript string escape)

Mostly with symbol `\` ... sometimes with `[]` or `HTML-code`

Ex.,

```
<td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/17d60601e17a27d3a0196470f00c55a4/5CF8DA8C/t51.2885-15/e35/50850072_2165205533518446_3117212119304625148_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px"> </center> </td>
```

Must be replaced with:

```
<td> <center> <img src=&quot;https:\/\/scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com\/vp\/17d60601e17a27d3a0196470f00c55a4\/5CF8DA8C\/t51.2885-15\/e35\/50850072_2165205533518446_3117212119304625148_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com&quot; height=\'200px\' width=\'200px\'> <\/center> <\/td>
```

You can try such operations here - - https://liveweave.com/
It has comfortable coloring, which tells, if there is a mistake.

---

P.s. 'could you explain a little more?':

```
<table id="AnyName"> ... </table>
```

Each HTML element can have a unique Id, which can be targeted from JavaScript.
Also, if you select classes in CSS with `.class {}`... ID can be selected with `#id {}`. So, we make initially invisible table with `#AnyName {display: none}`

And after click... if username and password match - we get element by ID and make it visible:

```
document.getElementById('AnyName').style.display = 'block';
```

It says "Take element with this ID, and change it's style"

There could be `.style.border = '1px solid red';`

or `.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

But we need to make it visible... so, `display = 'block';`

Comment: thanks for taking your time and helping. but could you explain a little more? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. I got two for you:

1. solution: redirect to new Page
2. solution: do an Ajax-Call and replace content with the table

Here some code:

```js
function getAjax(url, success) {
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) success(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.send();
    return xhr;
}

// example request
//getAjax('http://foo.bar/?p1=1&p2=Hello+World', function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>balalar</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function check(){

var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "user1" && password == "1234"){

        alert("hello user")

        // 1. Solution - Redirect to another "Page"
        window.location.href = "/table.html?username="+username;
        
        // 2. Solution - do an Ajax Call and render response
        getAjax("/table.html?username="+username, function(response){
          // replace body with new content ("table")
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = response; 
        });
        
        
    }


      else
      { 
        alert("chek username and password"); 
      }

  } 

</script>

</head>


<body>

<form align="center">

     username:<input type="text" name="username"     id="username" /><br>
     </br>
     password:<input type="password" name="password"     id="password"/><br>
     </br>
     <input type="button" value="login" id="login" onclick="return
     check()"/>

</form>

</body> 

</html>
```

for both examples you need a file called `table.html` with the table content next to your `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are leaving the table and the login page in 2 different html files. put it in an html page and handle in the check function ():

```js
function check(){

var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "user1" && password == "1234"){

        alert("hello user")

    <!--want to put the table here. but it breaks the function-->
    
    document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display = "none";

    }


      else
      { 
        alert("chek username and password"); 
      }

  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>balalar</title>

<style>

table, th, td {

    border:5px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {

    padding: 30px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: pink;
}

th {
    background: gray;
}

table{
  display: none
  }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<form align="center">

     username:<input type="text" name="username"     id="username" /><br>
     </br>
     password:<input type="password" name="password"     id="password"/><br>
     </br>
     <input type="button" value="login" id="login" onclick="check()"/>

</form>


<table align="center">
    <caption style="color: #ff99ac"> <h1>[BALALAR]</h1> </caption>


    <tr> <!--heading------------------------------------------------------------>

        <th>photo</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>info</th>
        <th>instagram</th>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--lucifer------------------------------------------------------------>

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/17d60601e17a27d3a0196470f00c55a4/5CF8DA8C/t51.2885-15/e35/50850072_2165205533518446_3117212119304625148_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>lucifersexdoll</center> </td>
        <td> <center>18</center> </td>
        <td> <center>instagram star and tiktoker</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lucifersexdoll/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--belle delphine----------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6331b02f48e920975e98434c595fd4ee/5CE47C32/t51.2885-15/e35/41760483_210825032975228_2673466538809180596_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="170px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>belle delphine</center> </td> 
        <td> <center>19</center></td>
        <td> <center>instagram star and snapchat thot</center></td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/belle.delphine/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--Georgia Twinn------------------------------------------------------>

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b4cdaabe45fd41c4d36e18c074a0cb71/5CEFBA3C/t51.2885-15/e35/43986219_288982548424250_1512646608107907870_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com" style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" height="200px" width="200" > </center> </td>
        <td> <center>Georgia Twinn</center> </td>
        <td> <center>15</center> </td>
        <td> <center> instagram star and youtuber</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/georgialeetwinn/"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px" > </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--lilsaggester------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7b351d27e76a70aed0dc97ca2946b31/5CF7E289/t51.2885-15/e35/44478694_259861178046212_7053862547100372241_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px" > </center> </td>
        <td> <center>hannah fabel</center> </td>
        <td> <center>16</center> </td>
        <td> <center>tiktoker</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aestheticallyhannah/"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px" > </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--cyxll-------------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center> <img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fe0da5e3353e102fd30a771e7f18d793/5CEA7C9B/t51.2885-15/e35/50510784_321000775215940_7823002975742791621_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="250px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>cyxll</center> </td>
        <td> <center>unknown</center> </td>
        <td> <center>instagram user</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cyxll/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a> </center> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr> <!--gal gadot---------------------------------------------------------->

        <td> <center><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/85ba393e3d05f6047fea8ac9ee61edd4/5D250597/t51.2885-15/e35/40265259_229384887926581_2920908417464813508_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com" height="200px" width="200px"> </center> </td>
        <td> <center>gal gadot</center> </td>
        <td> <center>33</center> </td>
        <td> <center>actress</center> </td>
        <td> <center> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gal_gadot/?hl=en"> <img src="https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/new-instagram-logo-png-transparent.png" height="50px" width="50px"> </a></center> </td>

    </tr>   


</table>

</body> 

</html>
```

If you want to display only one row in the table, set the id for it and set `display: block`  for the row with the corresponding id